# Is there an way to make WSL2 mount its folders on another drive outside Windows Preview Build 20211?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I've this SSD drive that I bought only for work so I would like WSL2 to write on it. Found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk) article which I was following thru, to find out [`wsl --mount` is working on Windows Preview Build 20211](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/926#issuecomment-696834213), not on my build (Win 10 1909 18363.1110).

Is there an way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Found out later, with a little change of terms on my research, that it could be done as in this tut here: https://www.sitepoint.com/wsl2/

To make it quick for anyone searching around here, you have to export your Linux image, unregister it from wsl and then import it again on the other drive. How it's done:

1. **List your distros**

In a Windows Powershell terminal, enter `wsl --list`. It should return what distros you have installed and if they're running.

2. **Export your distro**

In the same Powershell, enter `mkdir D:\backup` to make a dir for your backup then export it using `wsl --export <distro> D:\backup\<distro>.tar`. In my case, `wsl --export Ubuntu D:\backup\ubuntu.tar`.

3. **Unregister the distro**

You have to remove it from the C: drive with `wsl --unregister Ubuntu` and to make sure it worked, after the process is done list all distros again with `wsl --list`.

4. **Import the distro on another drive**

The syntax for this will be `wsl --import <distroName> <target\directory> <origin\image>`. So if you'd like to make an directory for your WSL in your new drive, just do `mkdir D:\wsl` or name it anyway you want. I already have a folder for that, so I went with `wsl --import Ubuntu D:\wsl-dev D:\backup\ubuntu.tar`.

You can verify if it's done by using the very same `wsl --list`.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to change your default user from root, follow below steps.

For Ubuntu 18.04, the command to change default user is

```
ubuntu1804 config --default-user <username>
```

Took me a while to figure out. Finally found it thanks to this [link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/128152-set-default-user-windows-subsystem-linux-distro-windows-10-a.html#option2)